# How to guarantee that only `Comparable` elements can be sorted in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, generics, haskell

I have implemented a sort algorithm in Java working on a list of Integers. Now I want to extend it to support general types. Specifically, it should be able to sort a list of elements which are comparable (e.g., by implementing the `Comparable` interface).

In Haskell, I can declare them as instances of `Ord`, declare the `sort` function as `Ord a => [a] -> [a]` and let the compiler guarantee that only elements *having an ordering* can be sorted.

My question is:

> How to guarantee that only elements *having an ordering* (e.g., by implementing the Comparable interface) can be sorted in Java?

Comment: `T extends Comparable<T>`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `T extends Comparable<? super T>`

Comment: I got it. Thanks. Would anyone mind posting your comment as an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a sort method using a constrained type parameter:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<T> sort(List<T> xs) { ... }
```